# Vim running commands with execute and normal

Tags: vim

I'm trying to search through a page for the word `CREATE`. I would then like to put `DELIMITER $$` above that line.

Here is my attempt.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
:execute "%normal! /CREATE\<cr>"."O DELIMITER $$"."<esc>"
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're close. To combine an action with a matching pattern, use the `:global` command. For prepending text in a new line, there are actually multiple approaches: The normal-mode `O` command can be used with `:normal`, or you can `:put` an expression `=` (instead of register contents) containing the text.

```
:g/CREATE/normal! O$$
```

or

```
:g/CREATE/put! ='$$'
```